# Forecast of spot electricity prices

Tags: r, multiple-regression, forecasting, autoregressive

I recently started a job in power trading. But due to a sudden change in employment I am required to work on econometric models to gauge the supply and demand side of national power markets. So something beween analyst and trader really. Since my job will also be to import power I have to gauge day ahead (spot) prices for a couple of markets. (I've got raw from Reuters for all my explanatory variables and I made pretty good experiences so far with their data)

I got so far: i have the impression that a dynamic regression would do the job quite well. The explanatory variables should be consumption, wind production, hydro production, solar production, nuclear production and gas prices (for the sake of simplicity I assume that consumption already takes care of the variable temperature). There is an additional variable I'd like to include, net import capacity, but I don't want to overdo it to start with.

Since there should be an auto regressive tendency, an ARIMA model should work? As software I chose R as MatLab was too pricey.

I appreciate that this is probably a rather basic question for this community. Nevertheless I would be very grateful if someone took the time to go through the process in an example (of course including R code would be wicked). I did find lots of papers online, nevertheless I would much prefer help from practitioners rather than academics. Also, I would be very interested in any form of relevant remote or f2f courses/seminars. If you know anything relevant please let me know. Equally, if someone with the right skill set is up for remote tutoring, please give me a buzz...

Thanks in advance!

Cheers
Markus

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help with this topic, but I guess you'd get better suggestions if you stated your background and how far you've gotten with your model